# How can i sort albums from songs?

Tags: java, android, sorting

So my problem is that when i try to sort the albums, the album title and album art are wrong.

I tried sorting the album ids but that doesn't fix it because album id have nothing to do with sorting the art apparently.

When i leave out the sorting everything is correct, but when i try to sort them the album names don't match the album art.

How can i sort my albums in the fragment?

Beneath here you can find my code.

Thanks in advance,

Vince

**SONG MODEL**

```
 // Columns I'll retrieve from the song table
    String[] columns = {
            SONG_ID,
            SONG_TITLE,
            SONG_ARTIST,
            SONG_ALBUM,
            SONG_ALBUMID,
            SONG_FILEPATH,
    };

    // Limits results to only show music files.
    //
    // It's a SQL "WHERE" clause - it becomes `WHERE IS_MUSIC=1`.
    //
    final String musicsOnly = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "=1";

    // Querying the system
    cursor = resolver.query(musicUri, columns, musicsOnly, null, null);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
    {

        do {
            // Creating a song from the values on the row
            Song song = new Song(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(SONG_ID)),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SONG_FILEPATH)));

            song.setTitle      (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SONG_TITLE)));
            song.setArtist     (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SONG_ARTIST)));
            song.setAlbumID    (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SONG_ALBUMID)));
            song.setAlbum      (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SONG_ALBUM)));
            // Using the previously created genre and album maps
            // to fill the current song genre.
            String currentGenreID   = songIdToGenreIdMap.get(Long.toString(song.getId()));
            String currentGenreName = genreIdToGenreNameMap.get(currentGenreID);
            song.setGenre(currentGenreName);

            // Adding the song to the global list
            songs.add(song);
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    else
    {
        // What do I do if I can't find any songs?

    }
    cursor.close();

public ArrayList<String> getArtists() {

    ArrayList<String> artists = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (Song song : songs) {
        String artist = song.getArtist();

        if ((artist != null) && (! artists.contains(artist)))
            artists.add(artist);
    }

    // Making them alphabetically sorted
    Collections.sort(artists, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    });
    return artists;
}

/**
 * Returns an alphabetically sorted list with all the
 * albums of the scanned songs.
 *
 * @note This method might take a while depending on how
 *       many songs you have.
 */

public ArrayList<String> getAlbums() {

    ArrayList<String> albums = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (Song song : songs) {
        String album = song.getAlbum();

        if ((album != null) && (! albums.contains(album)))
            albums.add(album);

    }
```

**SONG CLASS**

```
public class Song implements Serializable {

private long id;
private String data;
private String title = "";
private String artist = "";
private int   albumid      = -1;
private String album = "";
private String genre = "";


public Song(long songId, String songData){
    this.id = songId;
    this.data = songData;
}

public long getId(){
    return id;
}
public String getData(){return data;}

//Optional meta data

public void setTitle(String title){
    this.title = title;
}
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setArtist(String artist){
    this.artist = artist;
}
public String getArtist() {
    return artist;
}

public int getAlbumID() {
    return albumid;
}
public void setAlbumID(int albumid) { this.albumid = albumid; }

public void  setAlbum(String album){
    this.album = album;
}
public String getAlbum() { return album; }

public void setGenre(String genre) {
    this.genre = genre;
}
public String getGenre() {
    return genre;
}


}
```

Comment: Is so strange checks recyclerViewAlbums != null after set the adapter. It's 100% not null, or you will get NPE before check. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'm not sure why you are trying to sort by album when you are storing your returned values by song (see @Usman Rafi above), but..

**Add a global arraylist to the top of your fragment**

```
ArrayList<Song> Albums = new Arraylist<>();
```

**don't try to add genre information--you don't need it for your purpose**

> I tried sorting the album ids but that doesn't fix it because album id have nothing to do with sorting the art apparently.

Album art Uri's can be written as:

```
ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart"),
    cursor.getInt(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SONG_ALBUMID))));
```

So album art and album_id are actually inextricably linked.

> So my problem is that when i try to sort the albums...

Use MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "=1 ) GROUP BY (" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM in the selection variable of your query...

This will return unique album names (it will also only return one song within the album), if the album is repeated (by having several songs from the same album) in your mediastore database, only the first instance which matches your query will be added to your cursor.

> to sort the albums...

Use the sort order to sort cursor rows which are returned by album; I personally sort them using sql's alphabetical order (symbols, numbers, a, b, c....)

You should note here that sorting is case sensitive unless you specify "COLLATE NOCASE"

to write your query and sort it I would use the following code:

```
String[] projection = {"DISTINCT " + MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID,
                         MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, 
                         MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, 
                         MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, 
                         MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, 
                         MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
                         MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC};

String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + 
                   "=1 ) GROUP BY (" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID;

String sort = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC";

Cursor cursor = context.
                 getContentResolver().
                 query(MediaStore.Audio.Artists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                 projection,
                 selection,
                 null,
                 sort);
```

After this you can simply move through your cursor adding each row to the data object you built, there is no need for further sorting, and things should be in the proper order.

I personally just loop through

```
if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount >0){
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        //create new song item and add the album information you need
        Song album = new Song(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID)),
           cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA)));             

            album.setAlbumId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID)));
            album.setAlbumId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM)));

        //add the Song item to the global arraylist
        Albums.add(album)
    }
}

cursor.close();
```

you can now access the sorted album info by position in the arraylist...  you can get to the album art using the Uri builder i showed you at the top...

like this

```
Song Album = Albums.get(position);     
imageView.setURI(ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart"),
    Album.getAlbumID());
```

I hope this is useful to you.

**i still think you should build a data class called Album**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in my code i'm using a model class called "Song" where i set and get all information from the songs, but in your code you're using arraylists title, artist, art , but how can i store that information in my model class instead of arraylists?

Comment: I added the model class Song in my posts

Comment: I think you should build a data class called Album...  if what you are trying to do is list the songs in one album, then your Song data class makes sense, but then you would want to sort by track not by album...  if what you are trying to do is sort unique albums that are referenced in the MediaStore databases the code i provided is perfect...  you can just add your rows to the data class inside the while loop.

Comment: What i'm trying to achieve is a fragment that displays album art and album name.     https://imgur.com/ufQJkwk Here you can find an image of what i have, but as you can see, album names are sorted, but album art doesn't match the names.

Comment: I'm also using  public ArrayList<String> getAlbums() and  public ArrayList<String> getAlbumIds() and add information to them using song.getalbum and song.getAlbumID and then return an arraylist if i call those methods.

Comment: this will work exactly the way you expect it to...  however, you really should make some fixes to your data object...  there is no need to store song information, if what you are doing is looking at the albums....  it fits the code you set up...  but you need to fix the code you set up

Comment: Thanks for your time, i really appreciate it!

Comment: maybe a thumbs up if this was helpful...  selected answer if it solves your problem entirely???

Comment: Everything works, but i get an error if i add COLLATE NOCASE ASC to sort. 
E/Couldn't execute task: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "NOCASE": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT album_id, album, is_music FROM audio WHERE (is_music=1 ) GROUP BY (album_id) ORDER BY albumCOLLATE NOCASE ASC

Comment: When i remove it, the album art matches the names, but i have one album who shows a duplicate value. How can i remove duplicates?

Comment: it should have a space like this...  " COLLATE NOCASE ASC"  sorry...  i'm a bad typist

Comment: Any idea how to get rid of duplicates? one album is showing twice

Comment: You shouldn't have duplicates...  the album must have two entries with different album_id's...  the "GROUP BY" clause in the sql query will only return albums that have unique album_id's...  you might try grouping by album names rather than id's that might fix your issue...

Comment: "GROUP BY" album names did the job, thanks for your time. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174270/discussion-between-vince-and-me).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should make a class **Album** that holds the information of one specific album. Then either implement **Comparable** or **Comparator** Interface.

- **Comparable** if the albums are always sorted based on the same
  field.
- **Comparator** if you need to implement multiple sorting logic

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly, you're creating a list of strings which contains albums, then sorting this list independent of the original Query songs list. This means the album art remains untouched. I'd suggest implementing a comparable or comparator.

Comment: So how can i sort the album art? album art is fetched with the album id's but how can i sort albumids so that is matches the sorted album names? my album names are sorted, but album art doesn't match

Answer (score 0):

Without changing much in your code, you can achieve what you intend by sorting the Songs using a Comparator. Comparator can be used whenever you need to sort the objects using one of its properties (which is album name in your case for the `QuerySongs` object)

In your `getAlbumsId` method, add following

```
public ArrayList<Long> getAlbumsId() {

    ArrayList<Long> albumids = new ArrayList<Long>();
    Collections.sort(songs, new Comparator<QuerySongs>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(QuerySongs o1, QuerySongs o2) {
            return o1.getAlbum().compareTo(o2.getAlbum());
        }
    });

    for (QuerySongs song : songs){
        Long albumid = song.getAlbumID();

        if (! albumids.contains(albumid)) {
            albumids.add(albumid);
        }
    }


    return albumids;
}
```

Above will mutate the `songs` object, if you don't want that to happend, make a copy of it. Crux is to use comparator to sort the songs.

Comment: As an aside, one should prefer songs.sort(Comparator) over Collections.sort(songs, Comparator) for Java 8+

Comment: I tried your code, but getAlbum(); gives back a string, and operators < cannot be applied to a string.

Comment: I then tried wiith getAlbumID); but that doesn't work either

Comment: @Vince I just checked, you need to use compareTo method instead of < operator. My idea was to use some form of comparater. Try this 'o1.getAlbum().compareTo(o2.getAlbum())' instead of whole Condition. I have updated the answer.

Comment: I tried it but the only thing that is sorted are the album names, i already use a comparator inside my getAlbum(); so the names are already sorted, but the album art doesn't match the album name.

Comment: I know that i need the album id to fetch the album art work , but sorting album id's does nothing right?

Comment: I'm also using arraylists to store album name and albumids, should i make a class that holds that information and then use a comparator ?

Comment: @RickSanchez any idea how i can sort the album ids so that it matches the sorted album names?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the 2, coverart and title mismatch is because you sort one and leave out the other as is.
Consider the below example :

Album before sort -

1. World
2. Hello

Id before sort-
1
2

Album after sort
1. Hello
2. World

But id remains as such.
So when you build the uri for the coverart using the id list, id picked at position 0 is of album at position 1.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i still didn't figure out how to sort the album art work but i found out that the album id's are random numbers and the first album id starts with 7 till id 17 for some reason.

Comment: so when i use a compartor to sort them, it sorts them from id 7 to 17 but the album names which are sorted alphabetically don't match the id's.  Is there a way to like link the ids with the artwork?